# Is 賖 just a variant of 賒？

Tags: characters, etymology

賒 is clearly defined as “delaying payment for something” in Chinese dictionaries; it commonly appears in the phrase “賒帳”, which has a similar meaning.

賖 is a Chữ Nôm used to write “xa” in Vietnamese, which means “far”. To me, it seems like 賖 is a corruption of 賒, since 賒 is pronounced like “xa” as far as I know. On the other hand, there is no entry for “賖” in Chinese dictionaries, and might be a Vietnamese innovation. However, that would also be weird since its pronunciation is markedly different than other characters which also have the 余 component.

余- dư
餘- dư

Has 賖 ever been used in Chinese? Is it related to 賒?

EDIT: AFAIK, 賖 is also used for xơ, but this sound also doesn’t come close to the expected pronunciation.

Comment: http://www.guoxuedashi.com/zidian/8CD6.html

Comment: This means that 佘 and 余 were once the same character?

Comment: Yeah, so maybe the corruption process is the other way round. 佘 is a phonetic corruption of 余. Remember that 余 was originally very similar sounding to 舍. Wiktionary proposes that the part underneath the hat of 余 was corrupted into 示 to give a sound hint, as by the Ming era, 余 sounded nothing like 舍. (I didn't look too deeply into this)

Comment: That reasoning process wasn't entirely clear, let me rephrase: Components originally containing 余 as a sound hint would have ended up sounding like both "yu" and "she" in early Mandarin, as "she" and "yu" were originally something like /*la/. To facilitate the use of the sound hint 余 in characters which sound later like "she", part of the 余 component in characters sounding like "she" was corrupted into 示.

Comment: btw，賒賬 instead of 赊帳

Answer (score 2):

賖 is listed in *Hanyu Da Cidian* and defined as:

> shē
>   同“賒1”。

The entry for 賒 says:

> 1 买物延期交款。

---

[Zisea](http://zisea.com/zscontent.asp?uni=8CD6) also just notes:

> 同【赊】。

Not sure if their info is from 字海 or 汉语大字典 but there is no mention of Chữ Nôm in either of the references. It seems to just be treated as a variant in modern Chinese.

---

[Wiktionary](https://zh.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%B3%96) also gives the following references:

> **参考**
>   - 大字源：1673页，第14字
>   - 汉语大字典：第6卷，3643页，第2字
>   - 宋本广韵：165页，第3字
>   - 辞海：1275页，第5行，第4字
>   - Unihan数据：U+8CD6

and only mentions:

> 异体字
>    赊